# Looking for alternate expression of for function involving Catalan numbers and certain admissible triples $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^3$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, catalan-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{N}^3$  and admissible triple if  $x \geq 4, y \geq 4, z \geq 4$ and $x+y+z=n$.

Also, let $\gamma(x,y,z)=2$ if $x,y$ and $z$ are all distinct, $\gamma(x,y,z)=1$ if two of $x,y,z$ are equal to eachother and $\gamma(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{3}$ if $x=y=z$.

For each admissible triple $(x,y,z)$, consider the product $\Gamma(x,y,z)=\gamma(x,y,z)(c_{x-1}-2)(c_{y-1}-2)(c_{z-1}-2)$ where $c_n$ is the $n$-th Catalan number.

Let $p(n) = \sum_{\text{admissible } (x,y,z)} \Gamma(x,y,z)$

Looking for alternate ways of describing $p(n)$, closed form expression would be great, recursive definition would be cool also.

---

Some calculations that I've done by hand:

$p(12)=\frac{1}{3}(c_3-2)^3$

$p(13)=(c_4-2)(c_3-2)^2$

$p(14)=(c_5-2)(c_3-2)^2+(c_4-2)^2(c_3-2)$

$p(15)=(c_6-2)(c_3-2)^2+2(c_5-2)(c_4-2)(c_3-2)+\frac{1}{3}(c_4-2)^3$

I'm very poor at this type of counting thing.. Help appreciated!!

Comment: Can't help a ton, but a quick comment: I suspect you're intended to use one of the recursive forms of the Catalan numbers, probably $$C_{n+1} = \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+2} C_n$$ where $C_0 = 1$. I feel like those $-2$'s are supposed to be helpful rather than annoying, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: Thanks man. BTW, this isn't an exercise, but rather something I encountered in the mathematical wilderness whilst working on my dissertation O_o

Comment: Is $p(n)$ in OEIS?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really know how to type it in

Comment: Calculate several values $p(12), p(13), p(14), p(15),\dots$ and then enter the list of those values separated by commas here: https://oeis.org/. This is good practice whenever you have an unknown sequence, since if it has been studied enough before, there will likely be a lot of info in OEIS. If not, that is evidence you are in uncharted territory!